# How can I get multi selected cell items for NSArray?

Tags: uitableview

I've implemented multi selected UITableView.

I want to get multi selected cell informations.

For example, there are 5 cell items in myTableView.
and I touched 3 cell items. and then I want to remove these items.
(It likes multi delete of iPhone mail)

How can i get this information?

Answer (score 0):

This blog goes over it pretty well: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html

I won't paste in the code because it is significant, but I'm sure people would like it if you posted your implementation in your question as an edit after you are done.

Comment: Thank you. I will study hard... Code is difficulty for me understanding :)